# Entity Framework multiple optional relationships of same type with fluentapi

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a class that has two optional fields "TeamOne" of type "Team" and "TeamTwo" of type "Team". 
Teams can obviously exist without being asssigned to a game and shall not be deleted when a game gets deleted and vice versa.

Now I am trying to set the relationships this way:

```
HasOptional(x => x.TeamOne).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Game).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
HasOptional(x => x.TeamTwo).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Game).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I am running into the error

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'Infrastructure.DAL.Match_TeamOne' was not loaded because the type 'Infrastructure.DAL.Team' is not available.

Am I doing something wrong here?

edit: 
1 game : 1 TeamOne and 1 TeamTwo
TeamOne and TeamTwo are assigned to 1 game max

Comment: I think you will need to provide more information, not much to go on currently. Maybe give more context around the actual error message. From the error it says the schema isn't specified. Not sure if you are using migrations but maybe you haven't updated the database with the new schema?

Comment: I am doing automatic migrations. Schemas appear to be uptodate.

Comment: the error message says the type is not available. this might lead to non-public properties (or without proper getters/setters) or faulty compiling of the assembly.

Comment: Maybe you have old assemblies or maybe it didn't migrate this table. Shooting in dark, have you also tried deleting temp asp.net files and rebuilding? You may also want to decompile assembly and make sure the type is there. This is the root problem though from what I can see. `because the type 'Infrastructure.DAL.Team' is not available'` Make sure the type is there, loaded, and available.

Comment: It seems to be working when I remove one of the HasOptional()... instructions. So "HasOptional(x => x.TeamOne).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Match).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);" works but "            HasOptional(x => x.TeamOne).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Match).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            HasOptional(x => x.TeamTwo).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Match).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);" doesnt. I am unsure what the next steps would be.. any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create two relationships with one *inverse end*. Both `Game.TeamOne` and `Game.TeamTwo` are related to `Team.Game`. However, when coming from `Team`, to which `Game` should `Team.Game` refer? The one in which it is `TeamOne`, or `TeamTwo`? There's an ambiguity there. You'd need a second property of type `Game` to tie to `TeamTwo`. This would work:

```
HasOptional(x => x.TeamOne).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.HomeGame).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
HasOptional(x => x.TeamTwo).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.AwayGame).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But I don't think this model can be right. Can a team really have only one `Game`? That's an interesting competition model! I think teams can play in "many" games, and the mapping should look like this:

```
HasOptional(x => x.TeamOne).WithMany(x => x.HomeGames)
                  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
HasOptional(x => x.TeamTwo).WithMany(x => x.AwayGames)
                  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
```

... where `HomeGames` and `AwayGames` are `public (virtual) ICollection<Game>`.

Comment: Yeah I've just noticed what the problem really is... Yes a team can only be on one game at a time. When you think of "game" think of it rather as a match. Like Germany vs England for example. Germany won't be playing two games at a time. In my case there is no home and away team though. They are technically both away teams. I do not want to have to manager two tables for the literally the same type entity. There has to be a way?

Comment: One game at a time, yes. But you don't want to *store* one game only per team do you? Anyway, if you do, you can use the first mapping and adapt the property names. Or use your own mapping and replace one `WithOptionalDependent` call by one with an empty parameter: `WithOptionalDependent()`. Note that in this model, a team *can* be in two games at a time, as `TeamOne` in the first and as `TeamTwo` in the second.